# How to verify email through REST API

Tags: rocket.chat

Working on our rocket.chat with login through iframe. I can create users and login through iframe and the API.

My problem is that the users email isn't verify so offline email notifications won't work.

How do I verify their email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the [Rocket.Chat REST API](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/users/create) to create users, it accepts a property `verified` which will mark the user's email address as verified. An example of the **json** posted to the `/api/v1/users.create` with email being verified on creation is:

```
{
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "name": "Example User",
    "password": "example-p@ssw0rd",
    "username": "example",
    "verified": true
}
```

Using the `verified` property, you no longer need to directly update mongo or use the `/api/v1/users.update`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can verify a user by editing his account and checking the verified option. The user account can be edited from /admin/users

Comment: It's an okay solution but when you start to get more when 30 users it's difficult to maintain.
We set up a script to do it in MongoDB, but is not the optimal solution.

Comment: Well you can use the Rocket Chat API: https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/users/update